# showing popup window behind main window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

i want to make my pop up window will showing behind main windows.
say it window 1 is main windows and window 2 is popup window.
so when someone click window 1, window 2 will pop up behind window 1.
im already try `window.focus` and `window.blur` but no one working. remember this, I'm just making this one for learning.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var popup = function() {
        var lastShownTs = +localStorage.getItem("lastShown");
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var lastShown = null;
        if (!isNaN(lastShownTs)) {
          lastShown = new Date(lastShownTs);
          lastShown.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        if (lastShown == null || lastShown.getTime() != currentDate.getTime()) {
          window.open("example.com", "Window", "status=1,toolbar=1,width=1,height=1,left=5000,top=5000,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
          localStorage.setItem("lastShown", currentDate.getTime());
        }
window.focus();
popup.blur();
      }
    </script>

    <body onclick="popup()"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is referred to as a "Pop-under". 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open.

Alternately, here is a cheat using tabs ...

```
<script>
    function popunder() {
        var currentURL = document.URL;
        window.open(currentURL, '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, location=yes, status=yes, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes');
        window.location = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
    }

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="popunder()">Click here!</a>
```

Tested Chrome 62.0.3202.62.

Comment: that not what im looking for